# Searching for root cause of TC4422A failure

Tags: mosfet, driver, microchip, cmos, failure

I'm working with a device which employs the Microchip [TC4422A](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21946B.pdf) to drive a series LCR load in the low kHz range, PWM, 50% DC. The device actually has several of these driver circuits, for several loads, each controlled independently.

The system exhibits no failures when all loads are connected (several hundred systems in the field). In configurations where there is an unused driver circuit (load not connected) there are many failures of the unused TC4422A device. The unused driver output is connected to a trace on the PCB which is several inches long, all the way to the PCB header connector. The circuit is floating, nothing pulling it up or down, no capacitors, no steering diodes.

I believe the reason for failure is the floating output of the unused driver. I believe the otherwise floating circuit is being coupled to external radiated EMI, causing the voltage on the driver output pin to exceed maximum ratings, causing latch-up of the driver.

If there was an issue with the power supply/ground to the drivers, they should all be at equal risk for failure, however the unused driver is the only one failing.

What I don't understand is precisely how this is happening. I can't reproduce the failure on command. There are many variables in the final installation.

Any insight is greatly appreciated. My apologies for the general nature of the information, it's a sensitive situation and don't want to divulge too much.

EDIT: Added schematic

U2 with the load connected will not exhibit any problems. U1 with no load connected, output floating, fails at an alarming rate. The two devices share power supply, input driven from the same uC. U1 is not driven by software in this configuration.

[image: TC4422A Example Schematic]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. You could divulge a link to the datasheet, I'm sure, and a clue to what kind of chip the TC442A is (although you do give a few clues in the tags). You should probably give some sort of schematic sketch of the important bits otherwise we're all guessing.

Comment: Floating output also equals ESD target....

Comment: "The unused driver output is connected to a trace on the PCB which is several inches long, all the way to the PCB header connector." - Can show us the PCB layout, or a photo of the board? Does the device have any form of EMI shielding? What EMI sources do you think might be present?

Comment: "U1 is not driven by software in this configuration." - what exactly does this mean?

Comment: If the unused Driver input, from the MCU, is tri-stated then that 9amp power driver may oscillate. Ensure the input does not float; add a 100Kohm pulldown.

Comment: By the way, you've not shown the PCB layers for the failing IC.

Comment: If Bruce is right, no extra hardware is needed, just make sure your micro does not float unused ports. By the way it is wrong talking of floating outputs, they cannot float at all, they are either driving strong gnd or 12V even if no load is connected.

Comment: @BruceAbbott In the configuration of U1, I do not know what state the uC output pin is, high, low, or floating. I didn't write the software, I'll have to ask how they wrote it. Or I suppose I can just measure it/scope it see what potential it is at.

Comment: @carloc Yes I understand what you're saying. I see that the output is push/pull, so it's either high (Vdd-0.025V min) or low (0.025V max), not floating as I previously stated.

Comment: "I see that the output is push/pull, so it's either high (Vdd-0.025V min) or low (0.025V max), not floating" - So which is it, high or low? If it's floating a meter or scope will act as a pull-down and show 0V.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that Vdd was being raised beyond the maximum ratings, up to 23-24V. The mechanism was unexpected and took some time to identify.

Thanks everyone for your help.